# bad: impossible to install Dlib using pip

Tags: python, cmake, dlib

I have a big problem with `dlib` installation every time I try `pip install dlib` it gives me this huge error. I tried downloading packages upgrading system visual studio 2019 or c++ for `cmake`.

My operating system is `Windows 7 64bit` and I use `Python 3.7`.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\>pip install dlib
Collecting dlib
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/05/57/e8a8caa3c89a27f80bc
78da39c423e2553f482a3705adc619176a3a24b36/dlib-19.17.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: dlib
  Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.e
xe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\
\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8scxhav9\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"
'C:\\Users\\\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8scxhav9\\dlib\\setup.py'"'
"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'
"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'
))' install --record 'C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-hqcpwy4g\inst
all-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8scxhav9\dlib\
    Complete output (66 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Building extension for Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:05:1
6) [MSC v.1915 32 bit (Intel)]
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8
scxhav9\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\\AppDat
a\Local\Temp\pip-install-8scxhav9\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.7 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c
:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRA
RY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8scxha
v9\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.7'
    -- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
    -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 6.1.7601.
    -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.22.27905.0
    -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.22.27905.0
    -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Stu
dio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.22.27905/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
    -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Stu
dio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.22.27905/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe -- works
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
    -- Detecting C compile features
    -- Detecting C compile features - done
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual S
tudio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.22.27905/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual S
tudio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.22.27905/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe -- works
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
    -- Detecting CXX compile features
    -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
    -- Found PythonInterp: C:/Users//AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37
-32/python.exe (found version "3.7.1")
    CMake Error at C:/Users//AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-8scxhav9/dlib/d
lib/external/pybind11/tools/FindPythonLibsNew.cmake:122 (message):
      Python config failure: Python is 32-bit, chosen compiler is 64-bit
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      C:/Users//AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-8scxhav9/dlib/dlib/external/
pybind11/tools/pybind11Tools.cmake:16 (find_package)
      C:/Users//AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-8scxhav9/dlib/dlib/external/
pybind11/CMakeLists.txt:33 (include)


    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users//AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-8scxhav9/dlib/build/
temp.win32-3.7/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8scxhav9\dlib\setup.py
", line 261, in <module>
        'Topic :: Software Development',
      File "c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-pa
ckages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 143, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distuti
ls\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distuti
ls\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distuti
ls\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-pa
ckages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distuti
ls\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distuti
ls\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distuti
ls\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distuti
ls\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distuti
ls\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distuti
ls\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8scxhav9\dlib\setup.py
", line 135, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8scxhav9\dlib\setup.py
", line 172, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\subproc
ess.py", line 341, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\\\AppData
\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8scxhav9\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTP
UT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8scxhav9\\dlib\
\build\\lib.win32-3.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\\\appdata\\local\\p
rograms\\python\\python37-32\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_REL
EASE=C:\\Users\\\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8scxhav9\\dlib\\build\\
lib.win32-3.7']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\\appdata\local\pro
grams\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sy
s.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8scxhav9\\d
lib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-in
stall-8scxhav9\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__
file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compi
le(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\\AppData\Lo
cal\Temp\pip-record-hqcpwy4g\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-man
aged --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are already installed Anaconda, Try this

> conda install -c conda-forge dlib

Since dlib in conda-forge is the latest one. I hope this solution can help you solve the problem. :)

Comment: it keeps giving this error. solving environment:failed with initial frozen solve. @kawaekc

Comment: and failed with repodata  from current_repodata.json